# windows10/Mint installation which device is my empty partition?

Tags: linux, partition, windows

So for starters I'm completely new to this, I have little an idea what I'm doing. All i know is that i have an internal hdd split into two partitions, one with win10 installed and all my files in there, and one that i formatted to install linuxMint in. Now I'm facing this screen. I'd greatly appreciate it if you enlightened me on what all these things im seeing here are and what should i select without suiciding my computer. Thanks<3[image]

Comment: Windows will not show Linux partitions. And depending on if UEFI or BIOS install you may have lots of partitions with Windows. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations

Comment: Hmm I see... I dont understand a thing :p thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

It looks like sda4 is the partition you've created for your Linux installation, so select that one.

I'm guessing you created it using Windows, since it used NTFS for the file system type. That is no problem--the installer will reformat it to something Linux-friendly (I'd probably opt for the default option of ext4, unless you've done research and decided another option is preferable for your use case.)

Side note: Down the road, you might find that you want to downsize your Mint partition a bit so you can have a bit more free space for Windows 10, as you'll likely use that up if you continue using it much. You can judge based on your future usage of each OS. It's relatively easy to resize your partitions in the future, though, so need for you to worry about doing it before installing Mint.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? If not, please provide an update so I can clarify. (If so, can you please mark the answer as accepted?)